# Analyzing and Visualizing application log

Tags: logging, business-intelligence, data-analysis, tibco, spotfire

I'm currently using TIBCO SpotFire to analyze and visualize application logs, and i'm looking to replace it with a free of charge alternative software.

What I need is a tool that can analyze application logs and visualize them, and of course free to use with no limited time.

Can someone assist?

Answer (score 0):

The `pentaho report designer` is an open source software and understanding this tool shoudn't be difficult.

[Pentaho report designer](http://www.pentaho.com/)

Some more [open source reporting tools sofware:](http://opensource.com/business/14/6/three-open-source-business-tools)

Answer (score 0):

You could use this tutorial from Digital Ocean to set up the ELK stack, using ElasticSearch, Logstash and Kibana.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-elasticsearch-logstash-and-kibana-elk-stack-on-ubuntu-14-04